# Facebook Graph API Post to friends wall

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to post a message on some other user's wall as currently logged user? I'm able to post a message but it appears like that the other user has sent it, not me.

It was possible with old API (via stream.publish method) but I'm unable to duplicate that functionality with the new API.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this using their JavaScript SDK:

```
var user_id = "123456789";
var data = {
    name: "title of post",
    caption: "caption of post",
    description: "description of post"
};
var callback = function (response) {};
FB.api("/" + user_id + "/feed", "post", data, callback);
```

This will send a message with the data provided from the user currently logged in, to the user with the `user_id` specified.

In order to be allowed to post, you need to `publish_stream` permission, which you can request dynamically, by calling

```
FB.login(null,{perms: 'publish_stream'});
```

Comment: var data = {
    body: "Body of the post",
    message: "Message of the post"
}

Answer (score 0):

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

you have to use from / to params.

Comment: Note that you can only use a page ID if the user is an admin of the page.

Comment: where exactly is @nenad asking about page ?

Comment: I forget to mention that I want do this without user interaction, the old Rest API can do that via stream.publish method.

Comment: its the same, you dont use FB.ui but call the url directly. see the link if gave in my answer. you will need the publish_stream permission to do so.

Comment: @Rufinus I have tried, as it's written on the Link you send it will open a prompt or forwarded to it. In our case we need to write on the friends wall in the background without any output to the user as we do it with the old Rest API.

Comment: @Rufinus Allready tried yesterday, this way wont show the user as the person who has posted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. Its possible to post as a feed to the users wall...

JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Post("/me/feed", parameters) as JsonObject;

See the complete code here [Post To Feed](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/05/facebook-status.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used this single line of code to post on the friend's wall with friendID as the id of the friend to which I want to post
$attachment is the array with msg.

$result = $facebook->api($friendID.'/feed/','post',$attachment);

hope this would help..

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an active user session/cookie, you can post to a friends wall like so:

Javascript SDK

```
FB.api('/FRIENDSUSERID/feed', 'post', { message: message }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

Replace the FRIENDSUSERID with the user id of the friend.

PHP SDK 3.1.1

```
$publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
     'message' => "Your Message", 
     'link'    => 'http://example.com',
     'picture' => '',
     'name'    => 'App Name',
     'description'=> 'App description'
));
```

Just replace the $user variable with the user id of your friend.

I've put together a tutorial that shows how to do this among other things, its worth checking out: http://www.epixseo.com/index.php/facebook-php-3-3-1-and-javascript-sdk-graph-api-tutorial/